# Django - Stripe. You did not set a valid publishable key. Error that comes up when trying to incorprate stripe payments on a django website

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I'm working on a django bookstore website and there seems to be an error with stripe integration. I have an orders page that asks for payment information (I'm using the test API for now). I get the same error "You did not set a valid publishable key. Call Stripe.setPublishableKey() with your publishable key."

orders/views.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

class OrdersPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'orders/purchase.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ##Stripe.setPublishableKey('PUBLISHABLE_KEY')
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['stripe_key'] = settings.STRIPE_TEST_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
        return context
```

templates/orders/purchase.html

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}

{% block title %}Orders{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Orders page</h1>
<p>Buy for $39.00</p>
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="{{ stripe_key }}"
    data-description="All Books"
    data-amount="3900"
    data-locale="auto">
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your forms you need a `{% csrf_token %}` and `form action` that takes you to the charge page.

```
<form action="{% url 'charge' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}

<h1>Orders page</h1>
<p>Buy for $39.00</p>

<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="{{ stripe_key }}"
    data-description="All Books"
    data-amount="3900"
    data-locale="auto">
</script>

</form>
```

Also unless never set your pricing in your templates, this is asking for trouble. Set them in your view.